# How to overcome Error 1004 range of object _global failed

Tags: excel, vba

Here i am trying to copy data from one sheet to another, where i need to exclude one particular column from copy sheet

Like :
Think i have 2 sheets( with names as "Combined","HSR") from HSR i need to copy all the data to Combined sheet excluding column "D" values

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ColumnLetter As Variant
    Set ws = Sheets("HSR")
    Worksheets("HSR").Select
    lr = Cells.Find("*", , xlValues, , xlRows, xlPrevious).Row
    lr2 = Sheets("Combined").Cells.Find("*", , xlValues, , xlRows, xlPrevious).Row
    ColumnLetter = Split(ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Cells.Address(1, 0), "$")(0)
    Range("A2:C" & lr).Copy Sheets("Combined").Range("A" & lr2 + 1)
    Range("E2:ColumnLetter" & lr).Copy Sheets("Combined").Range("D" & lr2 + 1)
End Sub
```

I expect the output as, in sheet Combined i shouldn't get the values that are in column D from HSR sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ColumnLetter` is a variable. You are using it as a `String`.

Change

```
Range("E2:ColumnLetter" & lr).Copy Sheets("Combined").Range("D" & lr2 + 1)
```

to

```
Range("E2:" & ColumnLetter & lr).Copy Sheets("Combined").Range("D" & lr2 + 1)
```

Also few tips

1. `lr = Cells.Find("*", , xlValues, , xlRows, xlPrevious).Row` and `lr2 = Sheets("Combined").Cells.Find("*", , xlValues, , xlRows, xlPrevious).Row` will give you error if `.Find` doesn't return anyting. Handle it as shown in [.Find and .FindNext](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/11/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/)
2. Avoid the use of `.Select`. You may want to see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: '@Siddharth Rout' Thanks for your suggestion and solution